# How to change order of three columns on Foundation with no issues

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation 6 Framework and having some issues to change the order of three columns to looks like two on Desktop.

I have this layout on mobile breakpoint:
[ column 1 ]
[ column 2 ]
[ column 3 ]

and on Desktop looks like this:
[ column 2 ][ column 1 ]
[ column 2 ][ column 1 ]
[ column 2 ][ column 3 ]
 - - - - - - - ->[ column 3 ]
[Desktop Layout Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmKrO.png)

The page doesn't always has a big content on column number 2, sometimes it breaks:
[Desktop Layout with The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mS3p.png)

Since I can't use Flex Box yet, at first I tried to use Source Ordering (pull and push), but it doesn't works well with stacked columns (like columns 2 and 3 in this case). This solution was applied using the class float-right of Foundation on column 1 (assuming that column 2 already has 'float: right' because of being the last column).

My code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column small-12 large-4 float-right">column 1</div>
  <div class="column small-12 large-8">column 2</div>
  <div class="column small-12 large-4">column 3</div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know a good way to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Why you can't use flex grid? It's wide supported right now.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I must support some legacy browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The situation has changed since this question was filed. Push/pull is on its way out. Now in Zurb Foundation 6+ the XY Grid and source ordering is the preferred solution and in Zurb 7 the old float grids are to be deprecated. See https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/flexbox-utilities.html#source-ordering

The flexbox "order" css attribute can now be applied to individual items.

Or change the classes (eg "medium-order-1") as in the example:

```
<div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
  <div class="cell small-6 small-order-2 medium-order-1">
    This column will come second on small, and first on medium and larger.
  </div>
  <div class="cell small-6 small-order-1 medium-order-2">
    This column will come first on small, and second on medium and larger.
  </div>
</div>
```

[I realize the question is in the context of being unable to use flexbox, but this is currently the correct answer for the largest audience]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try breaking it down into one more set of rows and columns? For instance:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 large-8 columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">column 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">column 1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">column 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On small breakpoint, column 1 position should be first vertically.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well if it isn't too much content, a crude solution would be to load the column 1 content twice (once before column 2 and once after), give them id's and use css `@media` queries to display the one before column 2 beneath the small break point. A more complicated solution would be to give column 1 an id write some quick javascript to detach column 1 and then reattach it above column 2 on mobile. Using the second solution, you could detect the width of the browser when the page loads and handle it then

Comment: Yes, I have thought about these solutions. We have some performance problems on the page now. I would like not to use workarounds that would make this situation worse.

Answer (score 0):

By using correct order of layout and use of `pull` and `push` class. Look at this 3 column example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-6 medium-push-3 columns">
        Page content
    </div>
    <div class="medium-3 medium-push-3 columns">
        <h4>Course Details</h4>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Course Fee:</td>
                    <td>&pound; 50</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Course Duration:</td>
                    <td>1 Month</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-3 medium-pull-9 columns">
        <div>
            <h4>Course Map</h4>
            List of courses         
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

make sure you go through the Source Ordering part in the docs: 
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#source-ordering

you can use `small-push-x`, `large-pull-x` (replace x in numbers) to control the order of things

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”

Comment: you're right, although this question should be asked in google and not here IMHO

Answer (score -1):

Founds this one with "order-1, order 2"

ref https://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/50758-source-ordering-issue

Example

**Our priority is you**

EST skip tracers act with integrity, respect, and courtesy as
    it is our goal to provide service that exceeds expectations.
    We go the extra mile to ensure that you are satisfied with our results.